# Jquery - Detect browser close to force forms authentication signout in asp.net masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to determine when the browser is closed in an asp.net webforms application.   i need to force forms authentication signout on this event.   I cannot use anything in global.asax

I am thinking it will be a case of using the body onbeforeunload  event however I would need to bypass all other events such as submits and ctrl F5s.

I know there are issues with chrome not being able to find the onbeforeunload event as it needs to work in both IE and Chrome

Comment: Your question is not logical, why you need determine browser's close ?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743289/asp-net-mvc3-formsauthentication-how-to-expire-cookie-when-browser-closing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072961/forms-authentication-on-browser-exit

Comment: @TimurShahbanov wanting to logout on browser close is logical, but this approach is just incorrect. Non-persistent cookie will do this and he doesn't have to worry about detecting browser close. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

Comment: The requirement is that forms authentication is used and if user does not click "logout" button but closes browser then force forms authentication signout.

Comment: And you need to save his form ticket if he come back again ?

Comment: No the forms ticket is not need to be  persisted.